# docker0 network interface is screwing up my network

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, docker, ethernet

I've installed docker on Ubuntu 16. Now I can no more connect to my wired network : ubuntu is using docker0 ethernet interface to connect to the network (the wifi interface still works)

To resolve the problem I have to shutdown docker daemon and then shutdown docker0 interface :

```
$ sudo link set docker0 down
```

But if I start docker daemon again, it sets docker0 interface up and I loose my local network connexion.

What's wrong with docker0 interface ? How can I resolve this problem ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the docker network is interfaring with your host network. You need to customise the docker network , and set it to a different network than your host network before starting docker.

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/